# jQuery Autocomplete won't display JSON response from PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json, autocomplete

I'm stuck with the implementation of the jQuery Autocomplete. I'm using this tutorial: http://1300grams.com/2009/08/17/jquery-autocomplete-with-json-jsonp-support-and-overriding-the-default-search-parameter-q/

My jQuery code is this:

```
$("#quickSearchQuery").autocomplete("http://mydomain.net/json.php", {
    dataType: 'json',
    selectFirst: true,
    minChars: 2,
    max: 8,
    parse: function(data) {
        var rows = new Array();
        data = data.members;
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            rows[i] = { id : data[i].id, name : data[i].name, location : data[i].location };
        }
        return rows;
    },
    formatItem: function(row, i, n) {
        return row.name + ' (' + row.location + ')';
    }
});
```

A call to http://mydomain.net/json.php?q=Alb produces a JSON response like this:

```
{"query":"Alb","members":[{"id":"1","name":"Peter Albert","location":"New York"},{"id":"4","name":"Adalbert Smith","location":"Alabama"},{"id":"42","name":"Albert Einstein","location":"Vienna"}]}
```

My problem is: It just doesn't work. The Autocomplete doesn't appear, no elements are created.
If I run the code from the tutorial, everything is fine and I get the autocompleted list of cities. But even if I only change the source URI and from `data.geonames` to `data.members` (and so on), the autocompleter stops working.

What I've tried:

- I changed `dataType` to *jsonp* and *json*, but *jsonp* creates the 'invalid label' error on the JSON file
- I modified the PHP script's content-type with `header("Content-Type: application/json");`
- I tried all the other Autocompleters, but nothing changed
- I tried all the fixes I have found from responses at Stack Overflow and tutorials in the web
- I copied a JSON response from geonames.org into a file, uploaded it to my server and used this hardcoded response as lookup source. Still no autocompleter showing :(

Maybe you got an idea?

Thanks!
Joe

Comment: what domain you do use to call http://mydomain.com ?

Comment: Do you get any console errors?

Comment: No, there are no JavaScript errors. I currently run the script from localhost.

Comment: Is this a separate domain? If it is, you'll need to add a callback var for your PHP to wrap the JSON into a function.

Comment: Can you specify on this? I understand now that `jsonp` needs the JSON response to be in brackets not to cause the 'invalid label' error in the Firefox error console. And you're saying that it also needs a function. Like my_function({..JSON..})? What is my_function()? What impact does it have on the script?

The JSON response from the tutorial's website doesn't have a function wrapped around it.

Comment: I found the solution by myself and it is actually pretty easy. I just had to wrap the JSON response by a callback function (e.g. just a question mark), making it look like this:

    ?({"query":"Alb","members":[{"id":"1","name":"Peter Albert","location":"New York"},{"id":"4","name":"Adalbert Smith","location":"Alabama"},{"id":"42","name":"Albert Einstein","location":"Vienna"}]})

Answer (score 1):

with autocomplete, you must use the property id and value to make it working. Only those properties are used to render the list.

In your php object, declare something like this (this one comes from C#, but think that you understand it):

```
public class Product
    {
        public String id { get; set; } //must be used
        public String value { get; set; } //must be used
        public String marque { get; set; }
    }
```

and return the json-serialized string to the client.

The json is something like that

```
[{"id":"1","value":"UMTS","comment":"umts comment"},
{"id":"2","value":"RAN","comment":"ran comment"},
{"id":"3","value":"Swap","comment":"swap comment"}]
```

It will be auto-mapped in your JS and the autocomplete should work for now.